# AngularJS - How to send multidimensional $http.get() data

Tags: get, angularjs, urlencode

So I have a JSON array that looks something like this:

```
var myData = {
    foo : {
        biz : 'baz',
        fig : 'tree'
    }
}
```

This could be typed into the address bar like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/index?foo[biz]=baz&foo[fig]=tree
```

And this will work as expected.

The problem is that when I supply this `myData` object to AngularJS's `$http` service like:

```
$http.get('http://www.mysite.com', {
    data : myData
});
```

It escapes the query string and doesn't appear to even be the right format even if it weren't esaped in the weird way it is. It looks something like:

```
url?foo=%7B%22biz%22%3A%22baz%22%2C%22fig%22%3A%22tree%22%7D
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: probably better off posting the data... GET has character length limits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually in the right format. Assuming your back-end is PHP, when you do `$_GET['foo']` you will get `%7B%22biz%22%3A%22baz%22%2C%22fig%22%3A%22tree%22%7D`. The strange characters you see are because Angular is url encoding the string for you. This has to be done before transmitting the data. If you type it out as `foo[biz]=baz&foo[fig]=tree` in your browser, the browser usually urlencodes it automatically.

After `urldecoding` and `json_decoding` this, you will get the data you expect.

```
$foo = json_decode(urldecode($input), true);

Array
(
    [biz] => baz
    [fig] => tree
)
```

You can then access these as `$foo['biz']` and `$foo['fig']`

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/42V4eR91)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you for your quick response!