# What is better to use with cURL to make parameterized query

Tags: rest, post, curl, get

I am developing mobile application and now I'm preparing server API.
There will be search bar and user will be able to search other people by using mutliselects, inputs (just like web form).

And now the question is - what type of HTTP request is the most appropriate to send parametrized request to the server (using cURL) and get friends list as response?
I am thinking of using GET, but user will be able to set multiple values for one argument:
state - user can select more than one state

So I thought that using POST with request body in JSON format will be the best.
{"states":["state1", "state2", "state3", ...]}

But reffering to https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-16#section-7.5:

> POST is designed to allow a uniform method to cover
> the following functions:
>
> o  Annotation of existing resources;
>
> o  Posting a message to a bulletin board, newsgroup, mailing list, or
> similar group of articles;

Can anyone advise what type of query should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send multi-dimensional data in URLs like:

http://g.com/p.php?arr[]=1&arr[]=2

See:

[AngularJS - How to send multidimensional $http.get() data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192255/angularjs-how-to-send-multidimensional-http-get-data)

For another example.